# Only 1 of my text letters turns black

Tags: svg

I am creating a stack of 3 block letters on top of each other as a logo in Inkscape.  When I save as .svg and open in Blender to make it 3d, 2 of the letters remain red with black outline.  The 3rd letter turns black.

I am not sure if it is just the letters I am using, but I tried to do separate Red letters, each Object to Path, then saved as .svg. Then open in Blender but they are black.

I tried clicking texture, does not change.  Letters are 3" tall and I scrolled down the text type to find various ones that fit my theme.

My project has background solid color, other small text, boarders and everything keeps it's color, but that one letter.

Also tried saving as Plain .svg, Inkscape .svg, png.  Doesn't fix the problem.  I manipulated the other 2 letters and not the red C, so I went in, manipulated the red C, object to path, saved as .svg, opened in Blender and just that letter is black.

BTW I did make sure to check the original fill, stroke, etc. and they are all the same in Inkscape.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This  is all hard to follow without some images

Comment: same problem here.
I tried Inkscape and Adobe Illustrator.
In blender the text appears 0.01m below other curves.
Manually bringing them up takes a lot of time when many svgs. Have you guys found the fix?

Answer (score 0):

I was stumped by this issue as well. I was able to fix it by selecting the text, going under the "Object Data" property, and making sure the "Size" (under the Font menu) isn't set too low. In my case, anything less than .01 caused the problem.
If you set it too low, some letters go black. Raise it back up, they go back to normal. She falls down a well, eyes go crossed. She gets kicked by a mule, they go back to normal. I don't know.

If you need to get the text down past the point of the darkness setting in, just scale it instead of changing the size value.